# Why do plants have pith and how is it useful to them?

Tags: botany, plant-physiology

Many plants have pith, from walnut trees to corn to ragweed, but I can't think of anything it does them. What is pith and how is it useful to them?

Comment: Strange question: did you try to google? The [first entry](http://www.absoluteastronomy.com/topics/Pith) in my search results provides more than complete answer to your question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The pith (medulla) forms part of the [ground tissue system](http://www.uri.edu/cels/bio/plant_anatomy/glossary.html) of a plant, and specifically it is the ground tissue which lies interior to a plants vascular tissues (xylem, phloem etc.)

The ground tissue system is responsible for much of a plants metabolic functioning, and contains various specialized cell types which aid in photosynthesis and storage of photosynthesis products. The pith is made from parenchyma cells.